# ConfigurationManager Class and On Demand configuration changes

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

Are there any events that will fire if someone edited my custom made application config? I wanted to know such changes and apply it on my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a web application, then this happens automatically.

If it's non-web (and you have an app.config), use FileSystemWatcher to monitor the file. When the event files, restart the application (use Application.Restart()) - or just re-load your configuration values in whatever way you initially did. Like, if you have a public read-only property in a "Settings" class, just re-load the settings on that event. Hope that helps.

Comment: In fact editing the web.config with a new app setting is a way to reset IIS for your site.

Comment: Thanks! I thought ConfigurationManager class has other helper class that can fire if a certain changes are made on app.config files.

Comment: For app.config, not that I know of.